# Tornado, futures and blocking functions in Python 2.7

Tags: python, tornado, python-2.x

I was showing a friend about how to call blocking functions in `tornado` and I went with the classic example of a `RequestHandler` calling a function that sleeps for a few seconds.

```
def callback(self, future):
    print("Resolviendo el future")
    self.write(future.result())
    self.finish()

@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):

    print ("Llamando función que bloquea")
    # self.executor is a ThreadPoolExecutor
    self.executor.submit(
        partial(blocking_function, 10)
    ).add_done_callback(
        lambda future: (
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(
                partial(self.callback, future)
            )
        )
    )
    print ("Saliendo de función que bloquea")
```

I also made another `RequestHandler` using `gen.coroutine` instead of `web.asyncrhonous` so she could see different approaches to the subject.

So I ran the example in Python 2.7 (I have `futures`) and made some requests using `curl` and the handler with `@coroutine` and it all went well. But the `@asyncronous` handler hangs and never get's into the `callback` function. I switched to Python 3.6 using the same version of `tornado` and everything works ok.

My question is: is there a limitation in the `futures` package? I thought it was supposed to be fully compatible with `concurrent.futures`. Or it's maybe a Windows thing (yes, my friend works with Windows 10)?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fb7362505416267585f7f52fabfa4f0) runs fine on Python 2.7.13 MacOs 10.12.6.

Comment: Runs fine in Ubuntu 16.04 too, I'm about to think is a Windows thing but I don't like the "blame it on the OS" thing.